# Blurring viewController underneath another modally presented viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uivisualeffectview

I have an app with a hamburger-menu in the top-left corner.  When pressed, the menu fades in over the current ViewController at 90% opacity, presenting the app's main navigation options.

I am presenting the viewController from a page using the code below:

```
@IBAction func navToMenu(sender: AnyObject) {

    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainMenu")
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 112/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 0.9)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

How can I blur the viewController behind the menu when the it fades in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the blur effect to your View like this

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
//always fill the view
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Now write your code which add your view.

Comment: So I added this to my menu's viewDidLoad method and it works, but now none of my buttons show up.

Comment: Where is your buttons.??

Comment: They are in my menu's viewController.

Comment: Same .swift file, but in the menu's viewDidLoad.  Am I just blurring everything in my menu my placing it there?

Comment: You have to apply this effect only on your background view so remove self.view and add your view name there.